# "Current Instrumentation Disallows Attach" Instruments 4.5

Tags: ipad, ios6, mobile-safari, xcode4.5

i want to connect my iPad Safari with Instrument 4.5 installed with Xcode 4.5.2.
i was selecting allocations from instruments file menu-->new--> Choose a Template for the trace Document -ios -All -Allocations.
While i choose device and select attach to process then get a 
greyed-out "Current Instrumentation Disallows Attach" menu item.

anyone facing the same problem and whats a solution for it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think that only some of the `Instruments`' instruments allow post-launch attachment. For example, the 'Sampler' instrument allows it.

Try adding just that instrument to the blank template. You can add it from the Library button. See if it attaches like that.